# Integral $\int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{(e^x+1)(x^2+1)}$

Tags: integration

I do not know how to approach this integration problem.
$$ \int_{-1}^{1} \frac{1}{(e^x+1)(x^2+1)} $$ 
I tried some trigonometric change of variable and also tried to break it into two fractions but I failed!

Comment: How about breaking the integral into two integrals, over the non-negative $x$ and the non-positive $x$, and combining them suitably?

Comment: Another one https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1805550/42969 – both found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cint_%7B-1%7D%5E%7B1%7D%20%5Cfrac%7Bdx%7D%7B(e%5Ex%2B1)(x%5E2%2B1)%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: $\displaystyle\mathrm{f}\left(\,{x}\,\right) \equiv {1 \over \mathrm{e}^{x} + 1} = \Theta\left(\,{-x}\,\right) + \,\mathrm{sgn}\left(\,{x}\,\right)\,\mathrm{f}\left(\,{\left\vert\, x\,\right\vert}\,\right).\quad\Theta$ is the Heaviside Step Function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\displaystyle I=\int_{-1}^{1}\frac{dx}{(e^x+1)(x^2+1)}$

We know that $\int_a^bf(x)dx=\int_a^bf(a+b-x)dx$

$\displaystyle\implies I=\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{(e^{-x}+1)(x^2+1)}=\int_{-1}^1\frac{e^xdx}{(e^x+1)(x^2+1)}$

$\displaystyle\implies I+I=2I=\int_{-1}^1\frac{(e^x+1)dx}{(e^x+1)(x^2+1)}=\int_{-1}^1\frac{dx}{x^2+1}=2\int_0^1\frac{dx}{x^2+1}=2\tan^{-1}(1)$

which gives $I=\pi/4$